# Как правильно отправить переменную в конструктор?

Tags: javascript, html

Как правильно передать переменную в конструктор ?
Если ввожу числа то все работает и перемещает по страницам а если текст, то нет

```
const name = document.getElementById('inputFilter').value;

if (nextPage === totalPageCount) {
    $('#tagsPagesNavigation').append(
      "<li class=\"page-item active\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\"#\" >" + currentPageNumber + "</a></li>"
        + "<li class=\"page-item\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\"#\" onclick='new PaginationTag(" + nextPage + "," + size + "," + "\"" + sort + "\"" + "," + name  + ").writeTags()'>" + nextPage + "</a></li>"
        + "<li class=\"page-item\"><a class=\"page-link\" href=\"#\" onclick='new PaginationTag(" + nextPage + "," + size + "," + "\"" + sort + "\"" + "," +  + name  + ").writeTags()'>" + "Далее" + "</a></li>"
    );
}
```

Comment: У вас `nextPage` и `size` — числа, а `sort` и `name` — строки? Если да, попробуйте `name` окружить кавыками так же, как и `sort`, то есть `"," + "\"" + sort + "\"" + "," + "\""  + name  + "\"" + ").writeTags()'>"`

Comment: У вас немного сложная для чтения и письма конкатенация — попробуйте использовать одинарные кавычки, чтобы не экранировать двойные, а также не конкатенировать две строки подряд, а просто писать их одной строкой — так у вас вместо `"\"" + ","` получится `'",'`

Comment: Или освойте [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Спасибо большое :)